# TFS Service hook should not fire when work item is updated via REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure, tfs

I wrote a service hook on work item update but I don't want to fire the service hook when work item is updated from REST API, becz its the same data that other system had and it post to ADO and now ADO is posting back that data again, and it is creating duplicates, so any workaround to not to fire service hook when work Item is updated using the REST API or can bypass integration user, ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service hook will fire as part of the notifications process.  You can suppress all notifications by setting the URI parameter `suppressNotifications` to `true`.

An example request URI might be:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?suppressNotifications=true&api-version=5.0
```

See the [work item update API documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#uri-parameters) for more information.

Comment: Can you please help me with that too?
https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/7965/file-not-uploading-properly-in-azure-using-postman